# Sonata admin position field

Tags: sorting, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a Slide Entity which has a position field. I use this Entity to display a SlideShow in a frontend page.

So what I want to do in the admin dashboard is to be able to drag n drop each slide and set correct numbers in position fields.

I saw there are a "sortable" option in ManyToOne relation. But here I don't have ManyToOne relation.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Is [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-users/xWcwOjVUJAg) of any help to you? I also remember that Sonata Page Bundle uses drag and drop sorting in one of its admins. Currently [demo.sonata-project.org](http://demo.sonata-project.org) does not work, but you can check it later if you don't want to install Sonata sandbox or Sonata Page Bundle yourself.